# Using Python to get new URL after clicking Submit button

Tags: python, web-scraping, get, geolocation, gps

I am using Google Map to get the GPS coordinates of address that I am searching.  I want to get the URL after I chick on Submit so that I can extract GPS coordinates from URL. However my URL only shows:  https://www.google.com/maps

```
        url = "http://maps.google.com/"
        locationAdrs = '957 ASHBY GROVE SW ATLANTA' 
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/joe/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/PyOn/chromedriver")
        browser.get(url)
        address = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="searchboxinput"]')
        address.send_keys(locationAdrs)
        address.submit()
        url = browser.current_url
        print(url)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to re-affirm what the de-facto accessed link is, because your inputted link may not correspond with the DNS-route that finally connects you to the final destination. Then you have to wait for your browser to update before you return the new address that you are accessing:

```
url = "https://www.google.com/maps"
locationAdrs = '957 ASHBY GROVE SW ATLANTA'
browser.get(url)
address = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="searchboxinput"]')
address.send_keys(locationAdrs)
# address.submit() - doesn't seem to do the right thing.
url = browser.current_url # have initial url on same format before click is made to move away
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="searchbox-searchbutton"]').click()
while url == browser.current_url:
    time.sleep(2)
url = browser.current_url
print(url)
```

Output: 
`https://www.google.com/maps/place/957+Ashby+Grove+SW,+Atlanta,+GA+30314,+USA/@33.7500669,-84.4211224,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x88f5035d3de5336f:0x9ca82913b5ecbde!8m2!3d33.7500669!4d-84.4189284`

Comment: I am still getting https://www.google.com/maps for url.  In your while loop you are comparing url to driver.current_url,  I don't have driver variable, it produced run time error saying that driver variable is not defined. Should that be a browser variable?  When I changed it to browser variable I got same url: https://www.google.com/maps

Comment: Yes, in your case it should be `browser.current_url`. If you end up with "google.com/maps", set your initial url to this rxact string. The goal is to stay within the while-loop until it has changed. I'll update my suggestion to do this autonomously.

Comment: Notice how the url to google maps may be any of "google.com/maps", "www.google.com/maps", "maps.google.com", and I'm sure lots of other variations. These are all DNS-routes to "the same place", but the spelling matters within the while-loop. Re-setting url to whatever is returned by current_url right before moving away should solve that issue. I've made the apropriate change in answer. In the case that current_url does not work, you could use page_sorce.

Comment: It is working for me now, the problem was that I was using url = 
   'https://maps.google.com/maps' but should have used url = "https://www.google.com/maps"